# Finding a reputable seller for CR-10S

Tags: creality-cr-10

After doing a lot of research, I've decided I want to purchase a Creality CR-10S as my first 3D printer. I'm trying to locate a reputable, local seller. Other than Amazon, which seems to have a bit of a mark-up on price, I'm finding several websites that seem to be located outside of the US. Can anyone direct me to a seller located in the US?

Comment: Sorry, this sort of question is not a good fit for this site, there are too many variables, and the answer will be biased by people's individual experience.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane - in general I would agree that this type of question is not a good fit. In this specific case the question is "Can anyone direct me to a seller located in the US?". The only variable is geographical location, and is independent from individual experience, it's a matter of location on the surface of the planet. :)

Comment: when I ordered mine from a site that rhymes with rangcud, they actually had a US warehouse origin and it got here in a few days...

Comment: "Shopping Questions" are out of scope on Stack Exchange because its primary intent is to build up a database of information that can referred to by others that have the same question.  Questions that have answers that change over time are not a good fit.

Comment: This might be "shopping", or it might be supply chain.  Finding a distributor for particular components is a source of frustration for people not familiar with the distributors.  As a newbie engineer, and everything else as one point, finding sources was often the hardest step in a project.  I would also note that this question is not formed as an opinion question.  The OP isn't asking for "the best" or "the cheapest", but instead is seeking a US source.  As to changing with time, yes, distributors change, but good ones change slowly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do Shop recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve bought two printers (CR-10S and Ender 2)from Tiny Machines in Houston Texas.  They unbox them from China and assemble them and make a test print.  You get a checklist of the tests performed.  They will also flash a bootloader and updated Marlin for $10.

Yeah, you’ll pay more but if you spend any time in printer forums you’ll hear lots of complaining about missing/broken parts or DOA units.

They also stock spare parts here in the US.

Good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid unless you are available to accept the mark-up, you won't find a *reputable seller* other than in mainland China.  The entire business model of Creality is "cheap-cheap-cheap B2C" and any step you add to the supply chain (like a reseller) will be:

- **An added cost** that will be reflected on the final price you pay
- **A reseller-based initiative**, meaning that it won't be part of a "creality global distribution network", but the project of that local entreprenour.

That said, I read in a couple of places that **[tiny machines](https://www.tinymachines3d.com/) (Houston, Texas)** does a good job by testing each unit prior to shipping, and has similar lead times than good sellers from China (a couple of weeks).

Please note I am not affiliated with them in any way.  For that matters, I don't even leave in North America nor have purchased anything from them.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I continued to do research after I posted last night and I think I had my information backwards. I thought what I was seeing was a bunch of Chinese knock-offs and lots of varying prices with no understanding of who the actual manufacturer was. My understanding at this point is the company is Chinese and the suppliers outside of China are resellers. The mark-ups make more sense and I don't mind buying directly from China but will probably way delivery time with cost.

Answer (score 0):

My friend found an Ender 3, basically the same thing as a cr-10, at Best Buy. I wouldn't be surprised if you came across a cr-10s there as well. Keep in mind if you are going to buy one, to also get a warranty as printers can come damaged and break later. It is better to be safe rather than sorry.